# Why is PHP Foreach Loop only extracting last item in the element of JSON Array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I'm extracting data from a JSON file and have no problem getting all the items except for one because it is an array within the JSON array.

Here is a sample of the JSON array:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "12345",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-07-25T02:43:39.000Z",
    "channelTitle": "BuzzFeedVideo",
    "tags": [
     "celebrity",
     "celebrities",
     "seven",
     "seven years",
     "years",
     "different",
     "now",
     "then",
     "ariana grande",
     "justin bieber",
     "calvin harris",
     "miley cyrus",
     "abigail breslin",
     "daniel radcliffe",
     "neville longbottom",
     "matthew lewis",
     "buzzfeed",
     "buzzfeedvideo",
     "buzzfeedyellow",
     "video"
    ],
    "defaultAudioLanguage": "en"
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "700146",
    "likeCount": "16847",
    "dislikeCount": "596",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "1563"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I can get id, snippet:publishedAt, but when it comes to tags, only the last item in the tags array `"video"` is extracted with my foreach loop.

Here is my foreach loop:

```
$tags = $videosResponse['items'][0]['snippet']['tags'];

foreach($tags as $tag):
    $keywords = $tag;
    echo $keywords;
endforeach;
```

How do I get all the items within the JSON tags array starting from `"celebrity"` down to `"video"`?

**UPDATE:**

What I'm trying to do is update a php array file with the JSON data using file_put_contents.

Here is the structure I'm using.

```
    $tags = $videosResponse['items'][0]['snippet']['tags'];

    foreach($tags as $tag):
    $keywords = strtolower(replace_utf8_chars($tag));

    $new_array_line = " '" . $id . "' => array\n\t(\n\t'datetime' => '" . $publishedAt . "',\n\t'title' => '" . addslashes($title) . "',\n\t'description' => '" . addslashes($description) . "',\n\t'channel title' => '" . addslashes($channelTitle) . "',\n\t'tags' => '" . $keywords . "',\n\t'duration' => '" . $duration . "',\n\t'viewCount' => '" . $viewCount . "',\n\t'likeCount' => '" . $likeCount . "',\n\t'commentCount' => '" . $commentCount . "',\n\t'url' => '" . $url . "'\n\t),";
    endforeach;
```

and then the array pop and file put contents code is just below the `$new_array_line` variable.

```
    if(!array_key_exists($id, $videoids)) {
        $id_content = file($videoids_file); // Parse file into an array by newline
        $id_data = array_pop($id_content);

        if (trim($id_data) == ');?>') {
            $id_content[] = "\n" . '    // ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . ' | ' . date('M j, y h:i:s A') . "\n"; // Echo debug line
            $id_content[] = $new_array_line;
            $id_content[] = "\n".$id_data;
            file_put_contents($videoids_file, implode($id_content));
        }

        return array('title' => $title, 'description' => $description, 'channelTitle' => $channelTitle);

    }
```

If I end the foreach after this last part, then the first item in the tags array is output, but if I end the foreach before the if statement, then only the last item in the tags array is output.

Do I need some sort of time delay before the if statement is executed?

Comment: how is all your json?

Comment: it does not look like `tags` is in `snippet`, but a sibling -> `... "snippet": {"publishedAt": "2015-07-25T02:43:39.000Z", }, "tags": [...`, so not sure why you have `$videosResponse['items'][0]['snippet']['tags'];` and not `$videosResponse['items'][0]['tags'];`

Comment: tags is a sibling of snippet. trust me.

Comment: i tested your json and it is built wrong. you can tested [here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: a sibling or a child? your `$tags = $videosResponse['items'][0]['snippet']['tags'];` says child, where `$tags = $videosResponse['items'][0]['tags'];` would be a sibling. If it is a child, then your code sample has an extra `}` before `"tags"`. Do a `var_dump($videosResponse['items'][0]['snippet']['tags'])` (or `var_dump($tags)`) to see what your structure is, and make sure it is valid.

Comment: it is valid. I may have not posted it all. I will repost the JSON.

Comment: I just now reposted the JSON to make sure I posted everything and didn't miss any brackets.

Comment: no need for down voting my question either.

Comment: I just tested your json and php code and it works for me. see http://3v4l.org/1DSJ7 (I did add `."\r\n"` to `echo $keywords."\r\n";` just for display).

Comment: worked for me too, here is the result of your code without any modification :
`celebritycelebritiessevenseven yearsyearsdifferentnowthenariana grandejustin biebercalvin harrismiley cyrusabigail breslindaniel radcliffeneville longbottommatthew lewisbuzzfeedbuzzfeedvideobuzzfeedyellowvideo`

Comment: are you really doing echo in the foreach loop? not assigning it to some variable and overriding it each time until keeping the last one which is 'video' ?

Comment: @SalemOuerdani you probably are on to it. My guess it that the OP is trying to access `$keywords` later on **after** the `foreach()` loop, and it is only the last value.

Comment: @Sean might be right. I'll post the code of what I'm trying to do. I'm updating an array file with the JSON contents using file_put_contents.

Comment: if you replace `$new_array_line =` by `$new_array_line .=` , it will not output the results you are looking for ?

Comment: @SalemOuerdani thank you for putting me on right path. I had to add the .= to `$keywords .= strtolower(replace_utf8_chars($tag));` and then end the foreach above the `$new_array_line` variable.

Comment: I can't believe I've been hitting my head for the past 3 or 4 hours trying to figure this out and all I needed all along was one little simple dot `.`

Comment: you're welcome! i'll post it to keep answer to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$new_array_line =` need to by replaced by `$new_array_line .=` otherwise the foreach loop will keep overriding it when evaluating the next tag value until keeping the last one which is related to the '*video*' tag.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>never heared of endforeach...</strike>
When the JSON is valid, you should be able to access the array with:

```
$videosResponse['items'][0]['tags'];
```

Comment: That's not what is causing it. Bracket or the other way, both ways produce same results.